# python replace multiple double characters using a dictionary

Tags: python, replace

I am looking to replace character pairs in a string using a dictionary in python.

It works for single characters but not doubles.

```
txt = "1122"

def processString6(txt):
  dictionary = {'11': 'a', '22':'b'}
  transTable = txt.maketrans(dictionary)
  txt = txt.translate(transTable)
  print(txt)
 
processString6(txt)
```

Error Message:

```
ValueError: string keys in translate table must be of length 1
```

Desired output:

```
ab
```

I'v also tried

```
s = ' 11  22 ' 
d = {' 11 ':'a', ' 22 ':'b'}
print( ''.join(d[c] if c in d else c for c in s))
```

but likewise it doesn't work

looking to use a dictionary as opposed to `.replace()` as
I just want to scan the string once
as .replace() does a scan for each key,value

Comment: `for k, v in d.items(): s = s.replace(k, v)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this piece of code to replace any length of strings:

```
import re

txt = "1122"
 
def processString6(txt):
    dictionary = {'11': 'a', '22':'b'}
    pattern = re.compile(
        '|'.join(sorted(dictionary.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)))
    result = pattern.sub(lambda x: dictionary[x.group()], txt)

    return result

print(processString6(txt))
```

Comment: In the general case, it would be a good idea to call `re.escape` on text inserted into a regular expression. Otherwise, you'll introduce bugs if you want to replace text that contains special characters.